# Remove outlier from time series data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, outliers

I have one-minute data:

```
# Import data
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download(tickers="MSFT", period="7d", interval="1m")
print(data.tail())
```

I would like to remove observations where minute difference is grater than daily difference, where we refere to day of the minute bar. I would like to apply this rule on every column except volume. Begining of the code:

```
minute_diff = data.diff()
dail_diff = data.resample('D').last().diff().median()

# here remove rows from data were minute_diff is grater than daily diff
```

Answer (score 0):

```
minute_diff = data.diff().reset_index()
dail_diff = data.resample('D').last().diff().median()

cols = minute_diff.columns.to_list()
cols.remove('Datetime')

for c in cols:
  minute_diff = minute_diff[(minute_diff[c] <= dail_diff[c])|(minute_diff[c].isnull())]

data = data.loc[minute_diff['Datetime']]
```

Comment: I confused you with my code maybe. It should test if minute diff is greater than daily diff for specific day. So daily diff is vector of dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
# Import data
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download(tickers="MSFT", period="7d", interval="1m")

data_minute = data.copy()
data_minute['Date'] = data_minute.index.astype('datetime64[ns]')
data_minute['Date'] = data_minute['Date'].dt.normalize()
#Create new column for difference of current close minus previous close
data_minute['Minute Close Difference'] = data_minute['Close'] - data_minute['Close'].shift(1)

#Convert minute data to daily data
data_daily = data_minute.resample('D').agg({'Open':'first',
                                             'High':'max',
                                             'Low':'min',
                                             'Close':'last',
                                             'Adj Close':'last',
                                            'Volume':'sum'
                                           })


data_daily['Date'] = data_daily.index.astype('datetime64[ns]')
data_daily['Date'] = data_daily['Date'].dt.normalize()
data_daily = data_daily.set_index('Date')
#Create new column for difference of current close minus previous close
data_daily['Daily Close Difference'] = data_daily['Close'] - data_daily['Close'].shift(1)

data_minute = pd.merge(data_minute,data_daily['Daily Close Difference'],how = 'left', left_on = 'Date', right_index = True)
data_minute = data_minute[data_minute['Minute Close Difference'].abs() <= data_minute['Daily Close Difference'].abs()]
data_minute
```

Comment: Difference is difference between crrent and lag value. Additionaly, last filter should keep only observations where defferences are lower than absolute of daily defference. NAd it should be applied on all columns.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

```
daily_diff = data.resample('D').last().dropna().diff() * 25
daily_diff['diff_date'] = daily_diff.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
data_test = data.diff()
data_test['diff_date'] = data_test.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
data_test_diff = pd.merge(data_test, daily_diff, on='diff_date')
data_test_final = data_test_diff.loc[(np.abs(data_test_diff['close_x']) < np.abs(data_test_diff['close_y']))]
data_test_final['close_x'].plot()
indexer = (np.abs(data_test_diff['close_x']) < np.abs(data_test_diff['close_y']))
data_final = data.loc[indexer.values, :]
```